# How to extend default user registration page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I would like to extend the default user registration page by adding more fields that will be stored in the same `users` table of database with the default fields.

What is the easiest way to do that? Could explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7, you just add the fields to the user entity in "Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage fields."
Then, for every field there is the "Display on user registration form" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want different registration profiles for different roles on Drupal 7, try these two modules:

**[Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2):**

> Designed to be the successor of the core profile module [...] this module provides a new, fieldable 'profile' entity - leverage the power of fields!

**[Profile2 Registration Path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath):**

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths per Profile2 profile type.