# How do I make a Registration page in Druapl 7

Tags: entities

im very new to Drupal 7, and I need help creating a register page with a few fields.

Comment: There are a few questions around here regarding user registration.  [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11502/how-to-extend-default-user-registration-page-in-drupal-7) kind of covers what you're after.  That said however, your question shows a distinct lack of research.

Answer (score 3):

Using custom forms for registration is not at all Suggested ! Follow below steps to solve the issue.

- Login as super admin
- Go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields
- Add New Fields
- Check Display on User Registration form in field settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do i make a field for date of birth? and do also what happens if i tick "Required Field"?

Comment: Use date module http://drupal.org/project/date for date of birth field, If you tick "Required Field" then field should be mandatory to complete registration....